# How to elect new Master in Cluster?

Tags: java

I am developing an application based on clusters. It is based on Master/slave. My problem is when master is down, there should be mechanism to elect one of slaves as master. Can any one of you tell based on what parameters new master should be elected? Can you suggest any useful links?

Comment: Are you developing a cluster management system or a program that works on an existing cluster?

Comment: I've asked a similar question (and had some useful discussion) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523185/how-to-elect-a-master-node-among-the-nodes-running-in-a-cluster, you might want to have a look.